# Остановить скрипт при выполнении условия в потоке мультипроцессинга

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Как при работе с мультипроцессингом остановить весь скрипт, если в одном из процессов будет достигнуто условие? То есть, есть мультипроцессинговый пул с аргументами, аргумент попадает в функцию, в которой происходят определенные вычисления и если это вычисление верно - то дальше вычисления проводить не нужно и все активные нужно прекратить. Как это сделать? Пробовал sys.exit, но он почему-то вообще ничего не делает. На месте STOP SCRIPT его вставлял:

```
main(arg):
...
if x > 0:
   STOP SCRIPT IF CONDITION IS TRUE

if __name__ == '__main__':
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
   pool.map(main, [ARGS])
```

Comment: sys.exit я так понимаю прекращает один процесс, а мне нужно все сразу завершить

Comment: Если знаешь Английский или есть переводчик вшитый в браузер, то можешь посмотреть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447055/python-multiprocess-pool-how-to-exit-the-script-when-one-of-the-worker-process

Comment: А так, можешь посмотреть на методы `pool.apply_async()` и `pool.terminate()`, судя по комментариям на том треде они должны помочь решить проблему. Второй метод должен прекращать работу в теории.

Comment: @Andrew Спасибо большое за ответ! terminate не прекращает работу полностью, а с apply_async пытаюсь вот разобраться сейчас)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imap_unordered прервет выполнение, если raise произойдет

```
import multiprocessing, time

def main(arg):
    if arg == 2:
        raise UserWarning(arg)
    time.sleep(arg)
    return arg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        [*r] = pool.imap_unordered(main, list(range(5)))
    print(r)
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо большое, это то, что мне нужно было!